# Why do most mtb forks place the arch in front of the stanchions?

Tags: fork, design, mud

Similarly to the pictured below RS Pike, most fork manufacturers place the ark in front of the stanchions. This has proven to be a terrible solution when riding in muddy (or actually anything different than asphalt) conditions:

- on each rotation, the tire grabs some mud, dust, sand
- the first (and only) thing, standing in the way of the accumulated muck, is the fork brace
- the brace scrapes the mud
- the mud accumulates on the conveniently located flat areas behind the brace
- the stanchions work to push the contaminants into the bushings and seals
- the mud builds up indefinitely, instead of just falling to the ground

Why not place the ark to the rear of the stanchions, like [DT Swiss](http://f.lnwfile.com/84k3yv.jpg) do?

[image]

Comment: I think you mean the brace not the crown. I'd assume it's got something to do with rigidity and strength, that said I like how Manitou have thier brace at the rear.

Comment: Perhaps somebody has a [patent](http://www.google.ca/patents/US6607185) on placing it on the back of the fork.